# HBase: Trying to get the key value from a single row Result

Tags: hbase

Here is my code:

```
 HTable someTable = new HTable(conf, "table");
 Scan scan1 = new Scan();
 scan1.setFilter(new FirstKeyOnlyFilter());
 ResultScanner scanner = chkptTable.getScanner(scan1);
 Result firstKey = scanner.next();
```

What do I need to add here to obtain ONLY the key value from the single returned row?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a column family first.

Then iterate on your `ResultScanner`.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to hbase-0.96, you can use the following code to get the keys -


**Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();

HTable table = new HTable(conf, Bytes.toBytes("testtable"));

Scan scan = new Scan();

scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"));

ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);

for(Result result : scanner){

  System.out.println(Bytes.toString(result.getRow()))

}

table.close();**


However, since version -0.96 , its recommended to use `rawCells()` which returns `Cell[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use method **getRow()** of class Result.
It will return you the row key as a byte[].

http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html#getRow()